# Is it possible to recover a corrupt Samsung note?

Tags: notes, samsung-galaxy-a5

I lost some notes from the app Samsung Notes and I think I know why or at least how to reproduce the event. This happens when the phone has no space left (0 free bytes). When whatsapp app makes a backup at 2am, it eats a lot of space and then a few minutes later it comes back to normal. When I click in a note to open it while the phone has 0 free bytes, the note doesn't open anymore (message: "Can't open note. File corrupt"). It also doesn't let me share it anymore or convert it to pdf or text (message: "File corrupt or not supported). The phone is a Samsung Galaxy A5. I'd like to know if the notes are really lost forever or there is something I could do. Thanks.

Comment: If your flash has not a single byte free then every used app can't save anything at that time. So your data exists only in volotile RAM. In general Linux and Android should be used in a way so that you never encounter a no space left scenario, the strangest things can happen otherwise. I would consider this a problem of WhatsApp, it had to check free space while making backup and abort before it is running out of space. Also it is your task to ensure enough free space is a available.

Comment: Understood, too bad..